# apache2 working perfectly in ubuntu server via public ip using curl but not in browser

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

when i try  to acccess apache2 via public ip its showing "This site can’t be reached" but when i use curl it will get response this is my apache2 conf code

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port t>
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

added Listen 80 in apache2.conf file but this is not work

Comment: Your browser can not reach your webserver. This can have various reasons. My guess would be: your firewall is misconfigured (Port 80/443 reachable from outside?). It depends on your Ubuntu version which is firewall is preinstalled. First: Try to ping your webserver from outside to check if it is reachable at all.